# RxJava combine observables of two different types into an observable of a third type

Tags: android, rx-java

I have two server endpoints. 
Endpoint 1 takes a username and password and returns an id. 
Endpoint 2 takes an that and returns a UserProfile object.

I'm attempting to write a method that takes a username and password as a parameter and returns an `Observable<User>` (where User is an object made up of one field being the id from Endpoint 1 and another field being the UserProfile).

I've figured out how to call my first endpoint and use the resulting id as an input for the second endpoint, however I'm stuck on how to use the response from the second endpoint AND the response from the first endpoint to create the User object and return it.

This isn't correct, but it's the furthest I've been able to progress:

```
    public Observable<UserProfile> login(String u, String p) {
        return mNetworkApi.establishSessionViaCreds(u, p)
            .flatMap(s -> mNetworkApi.getUserProfile(s));
    }
```

This method takes in two strings and outputs an `Observable<UserProfile>`. I need it to output an Observable. A user can be created by taking the output of the first observable (String) and the output of the second observable (UserProfile). But how do I do it? Below is the method signature I desire but without the correct code to create an Observable.

```
public Observable<User> login(String username, String password) {
    mNetworkApi.doLogin(username, password)
        flatMap((Func1<String, Observable<?>>) s -> mNetworkApi.getUserProfile(s));
    /..Code to transform observable.../
    return ...;
}
```

Is there a way that I can create an Observable with a third type (User) from observables with two different types (String and UserProfile)?

EDIT
To explain the issue I'm having better. The first observable returns a string. That string is used as an input to the next observable, however after the second observable runs I need access to the string from the first observable and no longer can get a reference to it.

EDIT
This is as close as I can get it but it still won't work due to 'id' being inaccessible. If I could get a reference to id, then this would work perfectly but I call new User(id, userProfile), the id variable is inaccessible.

```
    @Override
public Observable<User> loginUser(String username, String password) {
    Observable<String> observableUsername = Observable.just(username);
    Observable<String> observablePassword = Observable.just(password);

    Observable<User> userObs = Observable.zip(observableUsername, observablePassword,
            (user, pass) ->
                mNetworkApi.establishSessionViaCreds(user, pass)
                    .flatMap(id -> mNetworkApi.getUserProfile(id))
                        .map(userProfile -> new User(id, userProfile))
    ).flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<?>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<?> call(User user) {
            return Observable.just(new User(id, userProfile));
        }
    });

    return userObs;
}
```

EDIT

```
Observable<User> userObs = Observable.zip(observableUsername, observablePassword,
            (user, pass) ->
                    mNetworkApi.establishSessionViaCreds(user, pass)
                            .flatMap(id -> mNetworkApi.getUserProfile(id)
                                    .map(new Func1<UserProfile, User>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public User call(UserProfile userProfile) {
                                            return Observable.just(new User(id, userProfile));
                                        }
                                    })
                            )
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an override of flatMap which allows you to specify a `Func2` to merge the original input and the output of the `Func1`.  For your case it would look something like:

```
public Observable<User> login(String u, String p) {

    return networkApi
            .establishSessionViaCreds(u, p)
            .flatMap(
                    // here is the normal Func1
                    new Func1<String, Observable<UserProfile>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<UserProfile> call(String id) {
                            return networkApi.getUserProfile(id);
                        }
                    },
                    // here is the extra Func2 which allows the merge
                    new Func2<String, UserProfile, User>() {
                        @Override
                        public User call(String id, UserProfile userProfile) {
                            return new User(id, userProfile);
                        }
                    }
            );
}
```

Or if you're using lambdas:

```
public Observable<User> login(String u, String p) {

    return networkApi
            .establishSessionViaCreds(u, p)
            .flatMap(
                    id -> { return networkApi.getUserProfile(id); },
                    User::new
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `Observable.zip`:

```
Observable<String> username = ...;
Observable<String> password = ...;

Observable<User> userObs = Observable.zip(username, password,
  (user,pass) ->
    mNetworkApi.doLogin(user, pass)
               .flatMap(id -> mNetworkApi.getUserProfile(id))
)
.flatMap(obs -> obs);
```

Note that the last line is needed because zip is `A + B -> C`, but in this case we're doing `A + B -> Observable<C>`, and we need to unpack the resulting Observable.

Comment: I made a mistake in my original question that has now been fixed and may affect this answer.

Comment: I don't think this works for my question. The .getUserProfile() method gets the id returned from the doLogin() method. In the example it's getting "user" as a param which I believe is the username in this case, which is incorrect.

Comment: Hell, it would'nt even compile in the original form, fixed. Do you understand it now?

Comment: It almost does what I need. See my second edit in the original question.

Comment: Move the last parenthesis of the getUserProfile call one line down.

Comment: Moving the paren allowed me to use the previously out of scope variable (id) however now I'm attempting to do an Observable.just(new User()) and am getting the error: "just in Observable cannot be applied to User". Which I don't understand because I thought that's exactly what Just is used for.